# Date to Timestamp issue while scooping data from oracle

Tags: oracle, hive, sqoop

I'm doing sqoop import from oracle to hdfs and create a hive table in parquet format.

I have a Date field in Oracle table( `mm/dd/yyyy` format) which i need to bring in a Timestamp format( `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss` ) in hive.

i used `cast(xyz_date as Timestamp)` in sqoop select query but it is save as Long type in Parquet file.

I checked hive table and NULLs are stored in hive table in `xyz_date` field.
I do not want to store it as a string. Please help.

```
system sqoop import -D mapDateToTimestamp=true \ --connect \ --username abc \ --password-file file:location \ --query "select X,Y,TO_DATE(to_char(XYZ,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY') from TABLE1 where $CONDITIONS" \ --split-by Y \ --target-dir /location \ --delete-target-dir \ -as-parquetfile \ --compress \ --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \ --map-column-java Y=Long
```

Here is my hive table format :

```
CREATE external TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc ( X STRING, Y BIGINT, XYZ TIMESTAMP ) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '/location' TBLPROPERTIES ("parquet.compression"="SNAPPY");
```

Comment: Do we have an answer for this. Even I am into similar situation